# Formatting this table

Tags: tables

I am terrible at creating tables, the following is the code from Excel2Latex

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Timeline} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Outcomes} \\
    \midrule
    Oct. 2014 - Dec. 2014 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    Jan. 2015 - Mar. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    Apr. 2015 - Jun. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    Jul. 2015 - Oct. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

which produces:

[image]

How can I make this look better? BTW, the length of the "blah"s is how long my actual sentence is.

Comment: Your second column should be `p` type, not `r`, for instance `p{8cm}`; alternatively, use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}` (requires `\usepackage{tabularx}` and, of course, `\end{tabularx}` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwrapping column types are not useful for this kind of table, so this is a case where `tabularx` is handy.

Note that the first column should either be centered or *left* aligned. I fixed also the spaces after the periods and the hyphen that should be an en-dash (`--`) or an em-dash (`---`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\label{tab:addlabel}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cX}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Timeline} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Outcomes} \\
\midrule
Oct.\ 2014 -- Dec.\ 2014
  & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
  & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
\addlinespace
Jan.\ 2015 -- Mar.\ 2015
  & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
  & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
\addlinespace
Apr.\ 2015 -- Jun.\ 2015
  & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
  & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
\addlinespace
Jul.\ 2015 -- Oct.\ 2015
  & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
       blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
  & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also added some vertical space between distinct rows, which is better when cells contain wrapped text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Modest Proposal (;): I added some colour with the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages, added some vertical spacing between groups of rows, and changed the secod column specifier from `r` to `>{\RaggedLeft}p{…}`. The `caption`package helps having a corrct vertical spacing between caption and table (and incidentally to change the caption formatting if you want). Finally the `makecell` package allows for a common formatting of the column heads.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\,\,}r @{\hskip20pt} >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{6cm}@{\,\,}}
    \toprule
    \thead{Timeline} & \thead{Outcomes} \\
    \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){1-2}
    Oct. 2014 - Dec. 2014 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          \addlinespace
    Jan. 2015 - Mar. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          \addlinespace
    Apr. 2015 - Jun. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          \addlinespace
    Jul. 2015 - Oct. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
            & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

[image]

**Variant**: If you want to have te caption on the left (or the right) of the table, youcan do that with the `threeparttableenvironment`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{threeparttable} 
    \usepackage{array, booktabs, ragged 2e, colortbl}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck = false, labelfont = sc}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\color{Tomato3}\bfseries}

    \begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}%[htbp]
  \centering \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
  \arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}
\begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\,\,}r @{\hskip20pt} >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{6cm}@{\,\,}}
    \toprule
    \thead{Timeline} & \thead{Outcomes} \\
    \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){1-2}
    Oct. 2014 - Dec. 2014 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          \addlinespace
    Jan. 2015 - Mar. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          \addlinespace
    Apr. 2015 - Jun. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
          \addlinespace
    Jul. 2015 - Oct. 2015 & 1. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
            & 2. blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%

    \end{document}
```

[image]